# Is current Fragment destroyed in every Replace transaction without addToBackStack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragment-backstack

Fragment A -> Fragment B (Replace Transaction added to back stack)

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragementB).addToBackStack("tag").commit();
```

Fragment B -> Fragment C (Replace Transaction NOT added to back stack)

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragementC).commit();
```

**During transaction Fragment B -> Fragment C will Fragment B be destroyed or not since backstack is keeping reference to it from previous transaction?**

AFAIK,in a normal replace transaction without addToBackStack ,current fragment is destroyed but here backstack is holding reference to that fragment from previous transaction

Answer (score 0):

I think yes. When you use replace method, current instance of fragment is destroyed. And when same fragment is called, you can see onCreateView() and onViewCreated() getting called again.

You can use .add() method instead of replace() method. This way fragment current fragment will be added to stack and not destroyed until you say replace or pop.